Запятая или тире при уточнении? (2)
В состояниях, предшествующих депрессии — при выгорании и стрессе, человек чувствует усталость.
Нужно ли ставить закрывающую запятую? А тире после слова "стрессе" — как закрывающее вставку? Или просто запятые с двух сторон лучше?

Правильно (по правилам):
В состояниях, предшествующих депрессии — при выгорании и стрессе, человек чувствует усталость.
Сравнить: В состояниях, предшествующих депрессии, а именно при выгорании и стрессе, человек чувствует усталость.
Здесь пояснительная конструкция входит в состав обособленного оборота.
Пояснение
Пояснительная конструкция в общем случае должна обособляться двумя тире, но перед запятой второе тире опускается:
Исходное предложение: В состояниях, предшествующих депрессии, человек чувствует усталость. Запятая закрывает обособленный причастный оборот.
Такое решение соответствует правилу Розенталя для обособленных приложений (пункт 10):
 Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:
 1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного 
 приложения ставится запятая. 

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Подобные задачи могут решаться двумя способами — по образцу обособленного приложения (одно тире) или вставки (два тире). Если использовать вставную конструкцию, то получаем:
В состояниях, предшествующих депрессии — при выгорании и стрессе, — человек чувствует усталость.
Ставится  два тире, а количество запятых (одна или две) уточняется по грамматике предложения. Здесь запятая относится ко второй части предложения (перенесенная запятая).  Вставные предложения и словосочетания, пункт 4 (3)
Интонация у двух вариантов разная: в первом  пояснительная конструкция не выделяется подчеркнутыми паузами, как в случае вставки. В то же время в заданном предложении нет особой необходимости использовать вставку, так как по семантике оборот близок к приложению.
О симметричном оформлении вставок
 Следует, впрочем, заметить, что часто встречается 
 своеобразная «симметрия» знаков (постановка 
 запятой перед вторым тире, если перед первым тире 
 стоит запятая): Когда я стану умирать, — и, верь, 
 тебе не долго ждать, — ты перенесть меня вели в 
 наш сад (Л.); Когда Косте, сиротке-то, пошёл 
 девятый годок, — а я в ту пору уже невестой была, 
 — повезла я его по всем гимназиям (Ч.); Когда всё 
 кончилось, — а бой длился около часу, — начдив сел 
 на коня и шагом поехал по равнине (А. Т.); Осенью, 
 когда поспевали яблоки, — яблоневые деревья были 
 гордостью семейства Поповых, — Анатолий обычно 
 спал на топчане в^саду, чтобы мальчишки не покрали 
 яблок (Ф.). 

Можно отметить, что для симметрии тоже нужны обоснования. В этих случаях речевой оборот по семантике является попутным замечанием автора, но не имеет непосредственного отношения к сказанному.

Можно сделать зап-тире как единый знак. Тогда не нужно будет разбираться, какой знак что открывает-закрывает.
В состояниях, предшествующих депрессии, — при выгорании и стрессе, — человек чувствует усталость.
Красиво ж.
